# Accessing various child elements of a table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access elements on the same `<tr>` level as seen below

```
<tr>
  <td ><input type='text' value='{$result['name']}' name='itemName' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' value='{$result['quantity']}' name='itemQuantity' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' value='{$result['cost']}' name='itemPrice' /></td>
  <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/></td>
</tr>
```

I want to click on the submit button and get each value from the three input fields to be sent over a post connection, so far I tried accessing these values by doing this

```
$(this).parent("tr").children("td input").val();
```

which results in an `undefined` result.

Comment: $(this).parents("tr").children("td input").val(); parents with an "s" since the parent of the input is the td. closest would be best in case you have multiple tr as parents (ie embedded tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent` only selects the `parentNode` element of the selected element(*if it matches the specified selector*), you can use `closest` method:

```
$('tr input[type=submit]').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').serializeArray();  
   // Using "siblings" method     
   // var data = $(this).parent('td').siblings().find('input').serializeArray();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this still does return blank for me. In `console.log` I get `[]`

Comment: I think the problem is that there are dynamically added to the screen and maybe that might be causing an issue with me using this?

Answer (score 0):

Immediate parent of `submit` is `td` and not `tr`. So try this

```
$(this).parent("td").siblings("td input").val();
```